# Create Diagram in SQL Server Enterprise Manager (SQL 2000)

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the lowest permission level I need on a user to be able to create diagrams in SQL Server Enterprise Manager?

I'm currently set as data reader and I am unable to create diagrams. (I wouldn't expect to be able to at this permission level)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further investigation, with the dbo role, I was able to create database diagrams.

Answer (score 2):

The database diagrams feature is actually a quite powerful schema editor - you can change tables/fields and relationships as well. (don't know why they did it that way).  I'd imagine you need quite high permissions to be able to create diagrams because of the editing possibility - probably owner or ddladmin.